# Deleting 1 element of dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Array{
    T *arr; int n,val,count;
public:
    Array(int a):n(a){
        arr=new T[n];
        val=n-1; count=0;
    }
    void push(){
        if(count>=n){
            throw "Overflow. Array size limit exceeded";}
        else{
            int i; T num;
            cout<<"Enter no.: ";
            cin>>num;
            if(cin.fail()){
                cout<<"Wrong data type"<<endl;}
            else{
                for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                    *(arr+i+1)=*(arr+i);}
                *arr=num; count++;
            }
        }
    }
    void pop(){
        if(val<=0){
            throw "Underflow. Array limit has been exhausted";}
        else{
            delete[] (arr+n-1);
            val--; n-=1;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    int x,n;
    cout<<"Enter size of an array: ";
    cin>>n;
    Array <int>a(n);
    do{
        try{
            cout<<"Enter 1 to push,2 for pop and 0 to exit: ";
            cin>>x;
            if(x==1){
                a.push();}
            else if(x==2){
                a.pop();}
            }
        catch(const char* e){
            cerr<<e<<endl;}
        catch(int a){
            cout<<"Wrong data type";}
    }while(x!=0);


   return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this program was to add and delete element in a dynamically allocated array. While the push function is working perfectly, the pop function results in compiler showing core dumped.(Full error is too big to post here). I also tried using delete operator without [] but the result is same. Please tell me what is wrong with the pop function in this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't delete specific element in c type array.

```
arr = new T[n];
delete[](arr + n - 1);
```

one solution for you is to keep index to the top item in the stack, after each push do index++, and after each pop index--.

please read about C type arrays and how to work with them.

some notes
you should do the input for the element outside of Array class. 
call the class Stack, as Array is something else.